# Исключить пустые результаты Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi

В этом коде идет сортировка по строкам.

**Как решить такую задачу:** Если строка, **в memo**, заполнена то **учитывать эти параметры для сортировки**. А если **не заполнена** то не учитывать. В моем случае, получается, что все строки, даже пустые - сортируются. Что тут нужно дописать что бы так заработало ?

```
    //работаем по строкам в файле
    while not Eof(fall) do
      begin
     //читаем строку
      ReadLn(fall, S);
      if (Pos(AnsiLowerCase(Memo1.Lines[0]), AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) then
      writeln(REZ1, S);
      if (Pos(AnsiLowerCase(Memo1.Lines[1]), AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) then
      writeln(REZ2, S);
      if (Pos(AnsiLowerCase(Memo1.Lines[2]), AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) then
      writeln(REZ3, S);
................................ и так далее...
```

Когда делаю через чекбоксы + Edit, вот так то все намного быстрее работает (То есть ставлю галочку на те edit где они заполнены). Но так не удобно, через memo удобней:

```
while not Eof(fall) do
  begin
 //читаем строку
  ReadLn(fall, S);
  if CheckBox1.Checked and (Pos(AnsiLowerCase(Edit1.Text), AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) then
  writeln(f1, S);
  if CheckBox2.Checked and (Pos(AnsiLowerCase(Edit2.Text), AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) then
  writeln(f2, S);
  if CheckBox3.Checked and (Pos(AnsiLowerCase(Edit3.Text), AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) then
  writeln(f3, S);
................................ и так далее...
```

Comment: Убрать пустые из списка строк, запомнив их индексы. Отсортировать. Вставить пустые строки обратно по запомненным индексам.

Comment: Получается, даже если я ввожу просто одно слово отсортировать то все равно учитываются остальные строки. Из списка я все убрала. И за этого дольше работает сортировка.

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос.

Comment: Также непонятна связь между кодом в вопросе и сортировкой.

Comment: Igor, Исправила немного вопрос, посмотрите. Если не будет понятно  то я смогу привести полный код.

Comment: А-а-а, Вы говорите о фильтрации.

Comment: Да, да, да - Igor, я может не так выразилась. То есть программа сортирует строки по ключевым словам. То есть идет фильтрация.

Comment: Еще хотел кое-что спросить. У меня иногда появляются практически одновременные голоса за мои ответы - по несколько (много) штук. Вы про это ничего не знаете?

Comment: @Igor подозреваете накрутку?

Comment: @Kromster Подозреваю человека в лучших побуждениях. Все равно система превратит карету в тыкву.

Comment: Igor, Kromster, Голоса я ставила, прочитав нужные темы - заранее. А потом, те которые мне понравились, я их сохранила в закладки и после поставила плюс. Так что тут накрутки нет.

Comment: @Татьяна, движок StackOverflow рассматривает такие [почти] одновременные голоса как попытку незаслуженно повысить репутацию определенному участнику. На следующий день эти голоса будут отменены.

Comment: Igor, Я поняла. Тогда буду ставить на понравившиеся темы + периодически. Просто я от чистого сердца ставила эти +, даже ничего плохого в мыслях не было. Не переживайте, теперь буду делать все и по этим правилам. Приятного вечера, главное человеческое понимание, общение и это у нас есть.

Comment: @Татьяна Я не сомневался, что Вы это делали от чистого сердца. Меня беспокоило, в первую очередь, чтобы к Вам за это не применили административные санкции. До  новых встреч на StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (Memo1.Lines[0] <> '')
and (Pos(AnsiLowerCase(Memo1.Lines[0]), AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) then
  writeln(f1, S);
```

Comment: Тут почему то пишет ошибку. Не могу понять...

Comment: @Татьяна Какую ошибку?

Comment: И надо скобки вокруг условия добавить

Comment: Вот текст при компиляции:  Implicit string cast with potential data loss from 'string' to 'ShortString'

Comment: "Implicit string cast with potential data loss" - это не ошибка, а предупреждение ..

Comment: Все, разобралась. Получается у меня еще была ошибка что после then не было begin.  Igor, Kromster, очень оперативно помогли ребята .